# Which way should I follow for the load test in .Net?

Tags: c#, multithreading, load-testing, performancecounter, stress-testing

I saw a few ways for load test. However really I'm confused about it! Because my story is :

I  collect datas from a web service, and I serialize them to give somewhere. Someone wants to  calculate avarage time of my code(**from collect data to serialize them**) for 100 or 150 users. These users can access my code same time asynchronously. So I want to make specific load test just in my code. Which way should I follow? Multithread? ThreadPool? PerformanceCounter? in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anywhich way, really.

On non-tech: I'm detecting a bit of 'them against me/us' there; perhaps you can get 'them' to help you specify/build it?

More often than not, in these type of scenarios, it is better to keep the test drivers external, because

- you are testing real code, not test-specific interfaces
- you can distribute load across machines (even different types of clients)
- it is often easier to monitor the activity (using PerfMon, WMI, Process Explorer, bandwidth monitoring etc.)
- it can take a bit of complexity out of your system (by not requiring testing infra structure)

Most of this comes down to preferring *integration test* over *unit test* when doing stress tests. 
The other part comes from the UNIX filosofy: let each program do a single task well.

Comment: Hi sehe, If I understand your explanation wrong, please warn me.

Yes I can calculate avarage time of my whole project with external test drivers.Hovewer I can not calculate specific code! Because if I try the test drivers, they include to avarage time,  request and respons time of Web service.I don't want to do this.

Comment: "Someone wants to calculate avarage time of my code", so that was your own question. If you want to know relative usage of time, use a proper profiler. Of course, running with a profiler _will_ influence the times (though sampling profilers will have a low overhead), but that's Heisenberg. This method beats the crap out of any custom-built in terms of relevance and ease of implementation (the tools exist)